# Can't get all href links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get to these links of the clips on this website: https://twitchclip.io/
First i tried this code which would print out all the links on the site, but it doesnt print the clips' links... i think the problem is i need to switch to the frame the clips' links are on?

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

How do i switch to the frame? And get print a clip's link?

Comment: I don't see any iframes in that URL.

Comment: The iframes are added dynamically with JavaScript. You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver to emulate that in Python.

Comment: hey i am using selenium here, with that code i dont get the links of the clips... only some links on the top of the webpage...